# Why does Visual Studio recompile non dirty projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with a couple of projects with inter dependencies.

When I make a change in a project and recompile, Visual Studio recompiles all projects, regardless of whether I changed them (or any of their precedents) or not.

I am using only C# projects. I tried cleaning the output - no change.
I checked the dates of my files - no future date.

Has anyone seen this behavior? Is there a cure for it?

Comment: What language are you using? The C++ compiler behaves very different from say the C# compiler.

Comment: We have the same issue when we mix C++ and C# projects.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause for this problem is incorrect time stamps on your files.  Check the files in your project and make sure they are not time stamped at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

when you make a change to the project file you may change the include paths or the include path order. clearly this could change the result of the build even if you change the content of no header file. there are limits to the dependency checking. i don't know for sure exactly what is checked and how the dependencies are calculated but i would certainly prefer it to do the build rather than miss a dependency.